# c# Show dictionary with specific value in datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf, dictionary, datagrid

I have a specific json file:

```
    {
    "Time":{
        "2016-10-01":"00:00:10",
        "2016-10-02":"00:00:20",
        "2016-10-03":"00:00:30",
    },
    "Id":2,
    "Group":"Not found",
    "Name":"XXX"},
{
```

I have my DataGrid with binding:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ProcessListTable, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" AutoGenerateColumns="True"/>
```

With ViewModel:

```
    private List<ProcessInfo> listTable;
    public List<ProcessInfo> ProcessListTable
    {
        get
        {
            listTable = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<ProcessInfo>>(File.ReadAllText(pathToFile));              
            return listTable;
        }
        set
        {
            listTable = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(ProcessListTable));
        }
    }
```

`DataGrid` is showing `Id, Group and Name`. And I want it to show only 1 specific value from the `Time dictionary`. Like I'm choosing date from `DatePicker` or some other thing, and `DataGrid` shows only value with that `specific key`. I have been trying to do it with `foreach loop`, find the specific key and delete others but that wasn't working/I did something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

looks like you have a master-detail relation. 
have look at the documentation of [Binding (MSDN)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms752347(v=vs.110).aspx)

try to add a additional property for your selected ProcessInfo (Master)

```
public List<ProcessInfo> ProcessListTable
{
    get { return listTable?? (listTable = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<ProcessInfo>>(File.ReadAllText(pathToFile));); }
}

public ProcessInfo SelectedProcessItem
{
    get { return _selectedProcessItem; }
    set
    {
        if (Equals(value, _selectedProcessItem)) return;
        _selectedProcessItem = value;
        OnPropertyChanged();
    }
}
```

and change your XMAL
with a additional detail grid

```
<Grid>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition/>
                    <RowDefinition/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <!-- Master Grid -->
                <DataGrid Grid.Row="0" x:Name="MasterGrid"
                          ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ProcessListTable, Mode=OneWay}" 
                          SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedProcessItem, Mode=TwoWay}"
                          IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"
                          AutoGenerateColumns="True"/>
                <!-- Detail Grid -->
                <DataGrid Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=SelectedProcessItem.Time, Mode=OneWay}" 
                          IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"
                          AutoGenerateColumns="True"/>
</Grid>
```